# How can I use my 6.4.1 version of Elasticsearch data in my new 7.3.0 version of Elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, json, elasticsearch

For example let's imagine that my Elasticsearch is deleted from my computer. But I still have the data of 6.4.1 version. And then I downloaded 7.3.0 version of Elasticsearch to my computer. Am I able to use that old data in the new version of Elasticsearch? If yes, how can I use it?

**EDIT:** I found out that when you upgrade Elasticsearch version, it automatically transfers the data from old version to new version.

Comment: Yes this is possible and requires the method of [full cluster restart](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-upgrade.html).

Comment: Apologies for the rather robust response you received on your question from earlier today. I think no offence was meant, but the message was a bit stronger than perhaps the writer intended. As per my own remarks on that question, it was too broad for this platform though - Stack Overflow's Q&A format works best with specific and focussed questions. Hope this helps!